# Using LibGDX with Android Preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, libgdx

I'm trying to use Andrioid's preferences system in conjunction with LibGDX's preferences system.  They both use SharedPreferences as a backend, so I figure they should be able to work together, but when I try to load the data in LibGDX's preferences, I don't get any data back.

My Android preferences.xml file (I know it's short, it'll  have much more later :P):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference 
        android:key="framerate"
        android:title="Set Framerate"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:defaultValue="25" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is my PreferenceActivity:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class WallpaperSettings extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
        }

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call it from a subclass of `com.badlogic.gdx.Game`, I use

```
Preferences pref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");
pref.getInteger("framerate");
```

The number of keys within `pref` is 0.

Anyone have a clue as to how this might be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6365#p32981 I was able to solve the problem.

Just a note, the code works for both Android 2.x and 3.0+.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class WallpaperSettings extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
        }

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("preferences");
            getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(0);
        }
    }
}
```